# Chrome 18, ExtJS 4.0 charts issue

Tags: google-chrome, extjs

I've just updated Chrome from 17 to 18.0.1025.142 and got all the ExtJS charts crashed in the web-site. The same issue reproduces on the [Sencha example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/charts/Line.html). Try clicking "Reload data". Any ideas?

Comment: It is working in `19.0.1084.1 dev` so it looks like they have already fixed it.

Comment: all my buttons started disappearing in chrome 18 too.

Comment: @ Neil there are lot of layout and chart related issues with ExtJS 4.0.7 and chrome 18. If possible do an update to ExtJS 4.1RC1 version, which should solve some of these issues. Also look at the issue link provided here as an answer and star the issue there. Maybe chrome developers can come up with a patch or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across the same problem. It looks like it's a bug in that version of chrome as the dev stream (v19) fixes the problem. It's a total PITA, but hopefully v18 won't be the current version for long. We just disabled the charts for that browser until it's sorted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. We'll suggest our users to wait a little or setup v19 :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111345) is an issue opened with chromium. Log in and star the issue so that it goes up in priority for chrome developers.

Also look at this thread for a workaround. Didn't work in my scenario but it might help you.
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?192175-4.0.7-Line-Charts-Broken-in-Chrome-18-Mac-(and-also-it-appears-windows)